# Limiting the apps that show up in the share chooser

Tags: android

I am implementing an app where I allow you to share a specific URL. When I hit share using this code:

```
   fun shareLink(link: String, text: String? = "") {
    val share = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    share.type = "text/plain"
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(R.string.invite_share_other_text))

    var extraText = if (!text.isNullOrEmpty()) "$text $link" else link
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraText)
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, activity.getString(R.string.invite_share_other_title)))
}
```

I get the following dialog (Samsung phone):
[image]:

However, when using CityMaps2Go to share a list (which results also in text + url) on the same phone what I get is:

[image]

Which is a lot of fewer options.

At first I thought this was CityMaps2Go just implementing their own dialog and thus having control over the options they allow, but when I tried this on my Google Pixel I got a different dialog (also with fewer options than other apps), which tells me the app is actually using the OS one and not a custom one:

[image]

I thought it was not possible to limit the apps that would show up when you launch an intent of text/plain, so what is happening here?

Comment: Please [share where the user wants](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html), not based on some heuristic of yours that assumes what the user wants.

Comment: @CommonsWare i do not want to limit, I am curious about whats being done here